# How to fix an import error using a Match object in React Router

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm a quite beginner to React and Redux...I need to use Match object in my application...but I'm getting the following error..

Attempted import error: 'Match' is not exported from 'react-router'.

Same error is given when tried with 'react-router-dom' as well.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Match} from 'react-router';
import GamesPage from './GamesPage'
//import './reducers/games'


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

        </div>
      <p>
          <Link to="games">Games</Link>
        </p>

        <Match pattern="/games" component={GamesPage} />

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: share some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Match** was component in the alpha release of React Router v4.

In the beta, **Match** has been renamed **Route** (and its props have changed so that pattern is now path and exactly is exact).Instead you should use a **Switch** statement, which will only render the first **Route** (or **Redirect**) that is matched. You can add a pathless component as the last child of the **Switch's** routes and it will render when none of the preceding **Route's** match.

You can check out the API documentation for more details.

Comment: Thank you..So is there any alternative for Match??

Comment: Yes Route does the exact same thing, its basically match renamed to Route. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
  import React from 'react';
  import logo from './logo.svg';
  import './App.css';
  import {NavLink, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
  import GamesPage from './GamesPage'
  //import './reducers/games'


 function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
       Sample application of react router dom
       </div>
       <Router>
       <NavLink to="/games">Games</NavLink>
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/games" component={GamesPage} />
        </Switch>
       </Router>
    </div>
  );
}   
    export default App;
```